# Recorrer Arreglo

Tags: php, array

Hola muy Buenas tardes les agradeceria quien pueda ayudarme, tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(20) {
    ["uuiddet"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["uuid"]=>
    string(36) "63ea13a8-1c32-4456-9604-4bfa9b953100"
    ["idprod"]=>
    int(69)
    ["intcant"]=>
    int(5)
    ["dblpreciobase"]=>
    float(164.57)
    ["dbldsct1"]=>
    float(148.11)
    ["porcdsct1"]=>
    int(10)
    ["dbldsct2"]=>
    float(146.47)
    ["porcdsct2"]=>
    int(11)
    ["dbldsct3"]=>
    float(144.82)
    ["porcdsct3"]=>
    int(12)
    ["dblprecioesp"]=>
    int(0)
    ["dblpreciofin"]=>
    int(0)
    ["dblsubtotal"]=>
    float(724.1)
    ["dbligv"]=>
    float(130.34)
    ["dbltotal"]=>
    float(854.44)
    ["intestado"]=>
    int(1)
    ["vr2alerta"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["vr2commentalerta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["numcodigo"]=>
    int(123456)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(20) {
    ["uuiddet"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["uuid"]=>
    string(36) "63ea13a8-1c32-4456-9604-4bfa9b953100"
    ["idprod"]=>
    int(70)
    ["intcant"]=>
    int(5)
    ["dblpreciobase"]=>
    float(164.57)
    ["dbldsct1"]=>
    float(148.11)
    ["porcdsct1"]=>
    int(10)
    ["dbldsct2"]=>
    float(146.47)
    ["porcdsct2"]=>
    int(11)
    ["dbldsct3"]=>
    float(144.82)
    ["porcdsct3"]=>
    int(12)
    ["dblprecioesp"]=>
    int(0)
    ["dblpreciofin"]=>
    int(0)
    ["dblsubtotal"]=>
    float(724.1)
    ["dbligv"]=>
    float(130.34)
    ["dbltotal"]=>
    float(854.44)
    ["intestado"]=>
    int(1)
    ["vr2alerta"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["vr2commentalerta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["numcodigo"]=>
    int(1285)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(20) {
    ["uuiddet"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["uuid"]=>
    string(36) "63ea13a8-1c32-4456-9604-4bfa9b953100"
    ["idprod"]=>
    int(68)
    ["intcant"]=>
    int(5)
    ["dblpreciobase"]=>
    float(164.57)
    ["dbldsct1"]=>
    float(148.11)
    ["porcdsct1"]=>
    int(10)
    ["dbldsct2"]=>
    float(146.47)
    ["porcdsct2"]=>
    int(11)
    ["dbldsct3"]=>
    float(144.82)
    ["porcdsct3"]=>
    int(12)
    ["dblprecioesp"]=>
    int(0)
    ["dblpreciofin"]=>
    int(0)
    ["dblsubtotal"]=>
    float(724.1)
    ["dbligv"]=>
    float(130.34)
    ["dbltotal"]=>
    float(854.44)
    ["intestado"]=>
    int(1)
    ["vr2alerta"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["vr2commentalerta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["numcodigo"]=>
    int(1062)
  }
}
```

Quisiera saber como se puede recorrer

Comment: es un array asociativo, es decir de clave valor verdad?

Comment: Si es correcto es asociativo

Comment: te posteé una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recorrer un array asociativo con PHP, lo puedes hacer con un ciclo foreach, del siguiente modo; te dejo un ejemplo

```
<?php
$valores = array("valor_uno" => "Alfredo", "valor_dos" => "Jorge", "valor_tres" => "Diana");

foreach($valores as $key => $value){
    echo $value.PHP_EOL;
}
//LO CUAL IMPRIMIRÁ
//Alfredo
//Jorge
//Diana
```

**¿Qué estoy colocando?**

> Paso dentro de los paréntesis del foreach la variable que almacena el
>   array, le coloco un alias llamado **$key** que a su vez accede al
>   **$value**; lo cual me va a permitir imprimir como puedes notar en el echo el valor de cada una de las claves, en este caso los nombres de
>   las tres personas

Ahora si quieres imprimir tanto la clave como el valor, puedes concatenar la variable **$key**

```
$valores = array("valor_uno" => "Alfredo", "valor_dos" => "Jorge", "valor_tres" => "Diana");

foreach($valores as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' '.$value.PHP_EOL;
}
//LO CUAL IMPRIMIRÁ
//valor_uno Alfredo
//valor_dos Jorge
//valor_tres Diana
```

**PERO YO QUIERO RECORRER UN ARRAY MULTIDIMENSIONAL**

> Entonces debes recorrerlo por medio de 2 foreach, el primero para el
>   arreglo principal y el segundo para los arrays internos

```
<?php 

$autos = array
                    (
                    array("bmw","ford","nissan"),
                    array("copet"),
                    array("Torre","Anzidi","Bleto")
                    );

 foreach($autos as $auto)
    {
    foreach($auto as $movil)
        {
        echo $movil ." ".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amigo si te fijas en el arreglo que coloque en la pregunta, es un arreglo con tres arreglos adentro

Comment: @AlexanderJ.Marcano ya mismo actualizo y te pongo un ejemplo de un array multidimensional

Comment: Excelente Amigo, ya lo resolvi con tu ayuda... Muchas Gracias....